# Using cmd to perform phonegap build --android, but i have this error coming out :processDebugManifest FAILED

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I am using cmd for phonegap build. After navigate to the folder where my phonegap project is, i typed `phonegap build -- android` as i want to generate a apk file. (I am new here, so still testing how to build this apk file)
After awhile, I have this msg:

```
:processDebugManifest FAILED FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

**What went wrong:**

```
Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk: minSdkVersion 7 cannot be smaller than version 10 declared in library C:\USers\xxxx\IdeaProjects\project_name\platforms\android \build\intermediates\exploded-aar\android\CordovaLib\unspecified\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
Suggestion : use tools: overrideLibrary = 'org.apache.cordova" to force usage
```

I cannot so understand about the message and don't have any ideas to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in your config.xml

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="10" />
```

you can use any value you like. Hope this solve.